# Сделать вкладки из записей wordpress

Tags: wordpress

На сайте [happylab](http://happylab.ru/#services) есть раздел услуги.
Как можно сделать такое в wordpress?
Выводить записи в таком же виде?

Answer (score 0):

Берите какую-нибудь красивую тему, которая поддерживает вкладки. Она выведет нужные записи в таком формате.

Comment: делаю на чистой теме bootstrap, взял с https://github.com/saxap/clean-wp-template